# How to display total amount spent on a particular day for a particular item using mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my table data:

```
  date       | item           price | 
+----+------------+-------------+----+
 2021-02-14 | Miscellaneous |   320 | 
 2021-02-14 | Miscellaneous |  1000 | 
 2021-02-14 | Labour        |   500 |
 2021-02-14 | Excavation    |  3400 |
 2021-02-14 | Cement        |   160 |
 2021-02-14 | Miscellaneous |   320 |
 2021-02-14 | Miscellaneous |   600 |
 2021-02-15 | Miscellaneous |   320 | 
 2021-02-15 | Miscellaneous |  1000 | 
 2021-02-15 | Labour        |   500 |
 2021-02-16 | Excavation    |  3400 |
 2021-02-16 | Cement        |   160 |
 2021-02-16 | Miscellaneous |   320 |
 2021-02-17 | Miscellaneous |   600 |
```

The query I ran is working fine for a particluar date

```
select item, date, sum(price) as total 
from transactions 
WHERE date = '2021-02-14' 
GROUP BY item
```

And the output is as below

```
+---------------+------------+-------+
| item          | date       | total |
+---------------+------------+-------+
| Cement        | 2021-02-14 |   160 |
| Excavation    | 2021-02-14 |  3400 |
| Labour        | 2021-02-14 |   500 |
| Miscellaneous | 2021-02-14 |  2240 |
+---------------+------------+-------+
```

Now I need the query which will give the below output for other dates as well and the expected output is as below:

```
+---------------+------------+-------+
| item          | date       | total |
+---------------+------------+-------+
| Cement        | 2021-02-14 |   160 |
| Excavation    | 2021-02-14 |  3400 |
| Labour        | 2021-02-14 |   500 |
| Miscellaneous | 2021-02-14 |  2240 |
| Labour        | 2021-02-15 |   500 |
| Miscellaneous | 2021-02-15 |  1320 |
| Cement        | 2021-02-16 |   160 |
| Excavation    | 2021-02-16 |  3400 |
| Miscellaneous | 2021-02-16 |   320 |
| Miscellaneous | 2021-02-17 |   600 |
+---------------+------------+-------+
```

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: `GROUP BY item, date` What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks man... I know I have missed something and very close to the query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should solve your problem...

```
select item, date, sum(price) as total from transactions GROUP BY item, date ORDER by date;
```